# Printing the return value from inet_aton() function

Tags: c, network-programming, inet-aton

I have this code which is working fine:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct in_addr addr;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s <dotted-address>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (inet_aton(argv[1], &addr) == 0) {
        perror("inet_aton");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(addr));
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

What I want to achieve is print the value of `inet_aton()` function. The description of function says that it returns a number, but when I try to print it, it says "cannot covert from address structure to decimal".

Comment: `addr.s_addr` should be an unsigned integer. See e.g. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? And can you please edit your question to include more details (like if it's a compiler error or a runtime error, the *actual* and *complete* error).

Comment: it was a compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this instead of your last `printf` worked for me:

```
printf("%d\n", addr.s_addr);
```

Comment: If you just do `printf("%d\n", addr);`, you'll get a compiler warning (since this is bad form), but it will still work.